# Code simplification

Tags: jquery, dictionary, highlight

I'm using the jQuery maphighlight plugin with a map of the U.S.

I have several states that are too small to put their abbreviations on them, so I have to put them to the side.

What I have done already is that when the user hovers on an abbreviation, the corresponding state is highlighted. That's working fine.

The "problem" I have is that, although the code works, it looks too repetitive to me, I've tried to simplify/optimize it, but the error I get is that all abbreviations highlight one single state and not the corresponding one.

Here's the code I have so far:

```
$(function() {
    $('.map').maphilight();

    $('#ma-link').mouseover(function(e) {
        $('#ma').mouseover();       
        }).mouseout(function(e) {
            $('#ma').mouseout();
        }).click(function(e) { e.preventDefault(); });

    $('#ri-link').mouseover(function(e) {
        $('#ri').mouseover();       
        }).mouseout(function(e) {
            $('#ri').mouseout();
        }).click(function(e) { e.preventDefault(); });
    $('#ct-link').mouseover(function(e) {
        $('#ct').mouseover();       
        }).mouseout(function(e) {
            $('#ct').mouseout();
        }).click(function(e) { e.preventDefault(); });

    $('#nj-link').mouseover(function(e) {
        $('#nj').mouseover();       
        }).mouseout(function(e) {
            $('#nj').mouseout();
        }).click(function(e) { e.preventDefault(); });

    $('#de-link').mouseover(function(e) {
        $('#de').mouseover();       
        }).mouseout(function(e) {
            $('#de').mouseout();
        }).click(function(e) { e.preventDefault(); });

    $('#md-link').mouseover(function(e) {
        $('#md').mouseover();       
        }).mouseout(function(e) {
            $('#md').mouseout();
        }).click(function(e) { e.preventDefault(); });

    });
```

Is there a way to simplify this?

Any help with this will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you post some of the HTML behind this too?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No change to your HTML required. Just replace your block with this.

```
$(function() {
    $('.map').maphilight();

    $('[id$="-link"]').each(function() {
        var child = $("#" + this.id.substr(0,2));
        $(this).mouseover(function() {
             child.mouseover();
        }).mouseout(function() {
             child.mouseout();
        }).click(function(e) { e.preventDefault(); });
    });
});
```

Comment: Raynos, your solution worked great as well. I actually went with your solution since it saves me a step. All I need to do is add the corresponding id's to the links and the elements that should be triggered, your script takes care of the functionality. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Add a shared class, like 'mapItem', and attach stuff to the `this` object.

```
$('.mapItem').mouseover(function(e) {
        $(this).find(selector).mouseover();       
    }).mouseout(function(e) {
        $(this).find(selector).mouseout();
    }).click(function(e) { e.preventDefault(); });
```

Comment: This one should've been the best and easiest solution but unfortunately it didn't work. Thanks though Zirak.

Comment: Well, I assume I should add the class 'mapItem' to the side link that triggers the effect on the state, like '#ma-link'. I did that and it didn't work. So I removed the class from those links and added it to the actual states, like '#ma', and it didn't work either.

Comment: You're right Zirak, it does work. However, my HTML structure is different to yours so I'd have to change it to make it work. Nonetheless, this is a very nice solution for a future structure similar to your example. Will keep in mind. Thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 1):

You could extract to a jQuery plugin:

```
(function($) {

    $.fn.bindMice = function(relevantSelector) {
        return this
            .mouseover(function(e) {
                $(relevantSelector).mouseover();       
            })
            .mouseout(function(e) {
                $(relevantSelector).mouseout();
            })
            .click(function(e) { e.preventDefault(); });
    });

})(jQuery);
```

You could then use like so:

```
$('#ma-link').bindMice('#ma');
$('#ri-link').bindMice('#ri'); // and so on..
```

This is just one way, there are many.

Comment: After trying all solutions your solution worked the best Eli. Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: I decided to use Raynos solution since it saves me the step of adding the list of states. Thanks again tho.

Answer (score 0):

Just make a function and pass the state id, simple:

```
function hoverState(state)
    $('#'+state+'-link').mouseover(function(e) {
        $('#'+state).mouseover();       
        }).mouseout(function(e) {
            $('#'+state).mouseout();
        }).click(function(e) { e.preventDefault(); });
}
```

Comment: Jakub, my code inspector says there's a syntax error on line 2. Thanks though.

Answer (score 0):

If you put a class on the states that are too small you could do this:

```
$('.too_small').mouseover(function(e) {
        $(this).find('.abbr').mouseover();       
        }).mouseout(function(e) {
           $(this).find('.abbr').mouseout();
        }).click(function(e) { e.preventDefault(); });
```

Where .too_small is on the same element as $('#ri-link') and .abbr is on elements like $('#ri-link')

Comment: locrizak, you mean .abbr on elements like $('#ri')? I tried it but it didn't work either. Thanks though.

Answer (score 0):

In general, the easier way would be to assign `rel` attributes to the relevant tags, and then just use one blanket assignment:

```
$('.link').mouseover(function(e)
{
    id = $(this).attr('rel');

    $('#' + id).mouseover();
}).mouseout(function(e) 
{
    id = $(this).attr('rel');

    $('#' + id).mouseout();
}).click(function(e) 
{ 
    e.preventDefault(); 
});
```

Comment: Didn't really follow this one. Thanks though.